# font-size with display:inline-block fails

Tags: html, css, mobile, font-size

i have a Problem with css font-size i cannot figure out.

Problem:

Simple Website with a footer. The Footer consists of two columns, each column with some links. The columns are based on display:inline-block.

The font-size is set in rem and works fine on Desktop. But on mobile, ie Android Chrome, the font-size does not scale: the text gets unreadable tiny, where other text ie in p-tags is readable as expected.

If I remove `display:inline-block` from footer-nav-column the text scales as expected but with the loss of the column-layout.

I tried float for columns too, but the text also scales to tiny Hieroglyphs.

What's wrong here?

```css
footer {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  display: block;
}

.footer-nav {
  padding: 2rem 0;
  background-color: #069;
}

.footer-nav-column {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.footer-nav-column>li {
  font-size: .9rem;
  padding: .5rem 0;
}

.footer-nav-column>li>a {
  color: #efefef !important;
}

.footer-nav-column>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer-nav">
  <div class="layout-center">
    <ul class="footer-nav-column">
      <li><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="footer-nav-column">
      <li><a href="/Legal">Legal</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Privacy">Privacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Cookies">Cookies</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Are you using any media queries that adjust the root (html tag) font-size?  Can you post the css for your root element (html) font-size?

Comment: No, i dont use media queries and dont adjust the root font-size. Here's my site: nukura.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed that you use text-size-adjust a lot in your code. How about setting the html tag's font-size to 100% (which is approximately 16px) and have all your rem measurements scale accordingly? Also, it could help to use this tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Place that in your head tag and see if it helps. I know I had font size issues and scaling problems in past projects like your issue but the viewport meta tag and setting the html font size have helped me out.

Additionally, try setting div.layout-center to 100% width and remove the min-width, so that it fits within your blue box.

Comment: Thank you a lot! html-tag font-size doesnt change anything (tried that before), but the viewport-meta-tag in combination with removing the min-width does the trick.